# Pine - labelling the second bar to open above the sma line

Tags: pine-script, trading

I'm new to pine and I'm trying to put a label on the second bar that opens above an sma line.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
study(shorttitle = "SMA - ST1", title="Simple Moving Average", overlay=true) 

MAPeriod = input(9, title="MA Period")
MA = sma(close, MAPeriod)

plot(MA, color=color.blue, linewidth=1)

MAcrossover = crossover(close, MA)
entrypoint = barssince(MAcrossover == 2)

if MAcrossover and entrypoint
    lun1 = label.new(bar_index, na, 'entrypoint', 
      color=color.red, 
      textcolor=color.red,
      style=label.style_xcross, size=size.small)
    label.set_y(lun1, entrypoint)
```

Any suggestions as to the best logic to use would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
study(shorttitle = "SMA - ST1", title="Simple Moving Average", overlay=true) 

MAPeriod = input(9, title="MA Period")
MA = sma(close, MAPeriod)

plot(MA, color=color.blue, linewidth=1)

MAcrossover = crossover(close, MA)
entrypoint = barssince(MAcrossover)
//greenbarcount = barssince(close > open)

if entrypoint==2 and MA<open and open<close and open[1]<close[1]
    lun1 = label.new(bar_index, high, 'entrypoint', 
      color=color.red, 
      textcolor=color.red,
      style=label.style_xcross, size=size.small)
```

Comment: If I wanted it to label the second green bar to open above sma line would this be correct? 

MAcrossover = crossover(close, MA)
entrypoint = barssince(MAcrossover)
greenbarcount = barssince(close > open)

if (entrypoint==2 and greenbarcount ==2)

Comment: According to the logic correctly, only condition should be `greenbarcount ==1`.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply :) 

What I mean is that I want to mark the second green bar to open above the SMA line. If I only factored in the greenbarcount as a condition, then it'd mark bars that sit under the SMA line. 

Also, is there a better way to identify green bars other than saying if a bar close > open?

Comment: Updated the script in the answer. Label on the second green bar  to open above the SMA line.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense - Lasly, what if I wanted it so that it had to be the second consecutive green bar to open in a row? Currently the logic holds true if there were to be a green, red, red, green - but what if you could filter it to only be the second consecutive green bar in a row?

Comment: It should be added to the condition `if` checking one more bar `open[1]<close[1]`

Comment: If the answer is complete for you, use the recommendations of the [article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)